# dose installing `xctool` will completely replace `xcodebuild` for all build?

Tags: xcode, xcodebuild, xctool

I want to install `xctool` for for understanding and practice but I'm not sure whether installing it completely replaces the `xcodebulid` or it will be a separate installation and will not affect my normal build from Xcode(play button)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`xctool` will not replace `xcodebuild`, contrary to what they state on their Github page. It is just built on top of `xcodebuild`, so you don't have to worry about loosing your `xcodebuild` when you install it. In fact, `xctool` would not work if the command line tools are not installed on the system.

If you consider using `xctool` for building, you may want to reconsider your choice. This is what they say in the docs:

> Note: Support for building projects with xctool is deprecated and will
>   not be updated to support future versions of Xcode. We suggest moving
>   to xcodebuild (with xcpretty) for simple needs, or xcbuild for more
>   involved requirements. xctool will continue to support testing

Comment: Thanks @lwaicko, its of great help.